# Android Studio - Genymotion - VirtualBox Do not work

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

I am a newbie in Android dev. My android studio worked well before, I am not sure why it happened like this a few days ago after my Windows 10 updated.

-> In Android Studio, it shows no connected device and no debuggable process.
[image: Link to Android Studio Picture]

-> In genymotion, when i try to run a device, there is a pop up like this
[image: Link to Genymotion picture]

-> In VirtualBox, as this pic [image: VirtualBox]

I tried some ways such as change IP address in Virtualbox or check the "Virtualbox NDIS6 Bridged NetWorking Centre" but they could not fix my problems even I delete and install them again.
Please suggest me some ways to solve it, otherwise any ways to completely delete all them and install again?.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need another version of VirtualBox. Genymotion requires VirtualBox 5.1.26 to work with Windows 10 Creator Update, see https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions.

Comment: Tks a lot Aurélien! They all work after I updated the Virtualbox