# Unable to start the virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

Today I have updated my Windows 10 to the latest version, after that my Genymotion have some error: "Unable to start virtual device...",
I have gone through all the answers in Stackoverflow and made all the changes like DHCP enable, but still I am getting the error. Can anyone help me please? 
I also checked the steps in [Genymotion problems in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709084/genymotion-problems-in-windows-10) but didnot work for me!

Comment: Better to delete the older virtual devices and download/install the new one. Might be the device configuration gets corrupted because of the update.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597269/android-studio-genymotion-virtualbox-do-not-work/48618842#48618842

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709084/genymotion-problems-in-windows-10

Comment: @AurélienGâteau I updated my Genymotion to V2.12.0, and my Oracle VirtualBox is V5.1.18

Comment: @RoyMiller Based on my search on net I think the problem is because of network obstacles, but I have no idea how to fix my problem

Comment: @Dhanshri This link was my first attempt...

Comment: @AlirezaAarabi you need VirtualBox 5.1.26 for Windows 10 creator update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Open Windows Network Connections
2. Right click on VirtualBox Host only adapter that created
3. Choose properties
4. Check "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver"
5. Disable and Enable the adapter.

Comment: update VirtualBox to the latest version @Alireza Aarabi